# iOS metal device becomes invalidate after app switched from background to foreground

Tags: ios, graphics, 3d, metal

Our game has a rare crash on iOS devices when it was switched from background to foreground, but we can't repeat the crash on our develop machines with logs.

The only information is the stack trace uploaded from user's device, and which appears the crash was occurred in the metal api, after validate the device. Sadly we can't get the metal report that describe why the device was invalidate.

This is the stack and the code where the app crashed below:
[image]
[image]

So my question is, in what condition the device will become invalidate on mobile devices? What's the different between the metal device invalidate and D3D9 device lost? BTW. I read the Vulcan document and there is a device lost condition, what is it exactly?

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: The first step is figuring out what message is being reported by `MTLReportFailure`. I suspect the issue has to do with a misconfiguration of your pipeline descriptor, as there's no real notion of device invalidation or loss, per se, in Metal. Usually, such errors will be printed to the debug console when running under the debugger in Xcode.

Comment: Thank you. But sadly it's too hard to reproduce this crash in Xcode.